# What is List Controls?

Tags: user-interface

While reading one of the Selenium books, I came across following statement:

"The Selenium WebDriver provides the Select class for working with Dropdown or List
controls."

But I didn't understand, what is "List controls" element?

Could someone explain me what it is or point me to url (something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list for drop-down list)?

Comment: Have you heard of google image search?

Comment: Yes, it's http://images.google.com/

Comment: Maxim Yegorushkin, do you have answer for my question?

Comment: [Here you go](http://bit.ly/Za9Kdy).